# I get a NullPointerException because of media player playing in background

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

a media player is running in my app in the background. as soon as I leave the app and call it up again from the background and perform an action, the app crashes with a NullPointerException. here is my code.

```
package com.example.logistikmeisterprfungsvorbereitung;



public class Begrusung extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView tw5,tw3,tw4,impressum, agb;
Button btn2;
MediaPlayer player;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_begrusung);


    // Dieser Code wurde nachträglich hinzugefügt 17.01.2021  19:00Uhr
    try {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.hintergrundmusik);
        player.start();
        player.setLooping(true);
    }catch (Exception e){

    }

   

    tw5= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    tw3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    agb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.agb);
    impressum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.impressum);
    agb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Agb.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    impressum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Impressum.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    

    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            player.pause();
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

        if (player != null && player.isPlaying()){
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
            player.release();
            player =null;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
2021-01-18 20:01:51.320 25805-25805/com.example.logistikmeisterprfungsvorbereitung E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.logistikmeisterprfungsvorbereitung, PID: 25805
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.pause()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.logistikmeisterprfungsvorbereitung.Begrusung$3.onClick(Begrusung.java:62)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7161)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:818)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27683)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

the way I see it, it is due to the MediaPlayer.pause () method how could I solve this problem? the activity has a button that takes you to the game. Then the sound should stop, when you go back the sound should start again.

Answer (score 0):

**Error explanation:**
You get a null pointer exception because the object MediaPlayer on which you are calling the *pause()* function doesn't exist anymore.

**Code explanation:**
When you leave an app and it is placed on the background, *onStop()* method is called and releases the MediaPlayer you have created and sets it to null. So, when you open again the app, you get the exception.

**Hint:**
Remember that *onCreate()* function is only called once, when the Activity is created for the first time.

**Solution:**
Try creating your MediaPlayer object in *onResume()* function, instead of *onCreate()*.